# What Could go Wrong with the VHDL Process

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I was wondering why this doesn't work in my final design:

```
process (clk_in, reset, start)
begin
    if (reset = '1') then
        init_counter          <= '0';
        init_counter_done     <= '0';
    elsif rising_edge(clk_in) then
        if (start = '1' and init_counter_done = '0') then
            init_counter      <= '1';
            init_counter_done <= '1';
        end if;
        if (init_counter = '1') then
            init_counter      <= '0';
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

My idea is that when start changes state (from 0 to 1) init_counter should become 1 for one clock cycle. It doesn't seem to work though.

Comment: "start" doesn't need to be in the sensitivity list, but I think your code should work. The problem may be outside, e.g. in your testbench.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can tolerate the delay/latency, I would recommend a small adjustment as follows:

```
process (clk_in, reset)
begin
    if (reset = '1') then
        init_counter          <= '0';
        init_counter_done     <= '0';
        start_d               <= '0';
    elsif rising_edge(clk_in) then
        start_d <= start;
        if (start = '1' and start_d = '0' and init_counter_done = '0') then
            init_counter      <= '1';
            init_counter_done <= '1';
        else
            init_counter      <= '0';
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

This will keep your process purely synchronous. Previously it was slightly "confusing" (and possibly so to the tools) since "start" was in the sensitivity list, but your outputs would only update on the rising clock edge.

If this still doesn't work, can you clarify if it doesn't work in simulation or in hardware? If it does not work in hardware, possibly you need to debounce your `start` signal?

Comment: Thanks. Your VHDL is of course 10 times more elegant. I even could get rid of "init_counter_done". My problem was actually that "reset" was not generated when I was thinking it was supposed to be generated (this is an NI box)... So your tracking of the change of state of the "start" signal solved the problem because there is no need to keep the extra state. This of course works given that "start" stays asserted for as long as needed.